# How to get changed data from Firebase Realtime Database onChildChanged Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Could successfully write sensor data to Firebase Realtime Database write data from Android app but could not achieve sync while reading data when onChildChanged is called.
This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
    String root = snapshot.getKey();
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
    data = (HashMap<String, String>) snapshot.getValue();
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(data.values());
    ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(data.keySet());
    String key = keys.get(keys.size() - 1);
    String value = values.get(values.size() - 1);
    assert root != null;
    switch (root) {
        case "temp":
            tempText.setText(value);
            Log.v(TAG, root + " = " + key + " : " + value);
            break;
        case "humi":
            humText.setText(value);
            Log.v(TAG, root + " = " + key + " : " + value);
            break;
        case "lght":
            luxText.setText(value);
            Log.v(TAG, root + " = " + key + " : " + value);
            break;
        case "stat":
            ledText.setText(value);
            Log.v(TAG, root + " = " + key + " : " + value);
            break;
        default:
            Log.v(TAG, root);
            break;
    }
}
```

[image: JSON Structure 1]

[image: JSON Structure 2]

[image: Log]

When a key-value pair is added to a child node, the onChildChanged gets called properly, but the logs do not show this newly added pair in realtime, instead it does with delay. The changed child node gets mentioned correctly; how to retrieve this newly added key-value pair in sync?

Comment: "could not" is a bit hard to help with. What data is this listener observing? If you `System.out.println(snapshot.getValue())` what does it show? If you step through this method in a debugger, which line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Please do check the json structure and log images.

Comment: Thanks for those. What is unexpected about those results?

Comment: I get the same key value pair for respective node everytime onchildchanged is called, and not the next pair.

Comment: And why is that not what you expected? Keep in mind: we only know what you tell us, or (better) what the code and logs show us. If you think `onChildChanged` should be called multiple times for different child nodes, can you show us why that is?

Comment: I have edited the post at the end. Sorry, asking a question for the first time.

Comment: That clarifications helps, thank you. Can you edit the question to also show: 1) the code that attaches the listener, including the location that the listener is added to? 2) the operation that writes the data that then triggers the listener? I also highly recommend checking out [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following the guidance in there makes it much more likely that someone here can help.